# Scala bitwise operators on Bytes

Tags: scala, bitwise-operators

I was trying to do some bitwise operators on bytes in Scala and I got some weird compilation-error:

```
scala> var a: Byte = 5 | 3
a: Byte = 7

scala> a |= 7
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Byte
              a |= 7
                ^

scala> a |= 7.toByte
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Byte
              a |= 7.toByte
                ^
```

So essentially I'm trying to create a `var a: Byte = <something>`, then when doing the bitwise-operators and equals to this re-assignable Byte it doesn't work, I have reported it as a bug but am I missing something? Is there a reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because the overloads of `|` are these:

```
def |(x: Byte): Int
def |(x: Char): Int
def |(x: Int): Int
def |(x: Long): Long
def |(x: Short): Int
```

As you can see, `|` returns either `Int` or `Long`, but no `Byte`, while your `a` variable has type `Byte`. Hence, it's unassignable.